# How to construct query to filter by pairs of keys in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

let's assume that I have collection called my_collection, with three documents:

```
{'_id": 1, 'foo': 'foo_val', 'bar': 'bar_val'},
{'_id": 2, 'foo': 'foo_val2', 'bar': 'bar_val2'},
{'_id": 3, 'foo': 'foo_val', 'bar': 'bar_val2'}
```

I'd like to query it by given pairs of key-values, in this case e.g. I'd like to filter it by:

```
[{'foo': 'foo_val', 'bar': 'bar_val'}, {'foo': 'foo_val2', 'bar': 'bar_val2'}]
```

so it should return documents with ids 1 and 2.

It there an elegant way to do this in one call to db? I tried using the `$in` keyword, but it doesn't work as I want.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use the `$or` operator:

```
db.your_collection.find({$or:[{'foo': 'foo_val', 'bar': 'bar_val'},{'foo': 'foo_val2', 'bar': 'bar_val2'}]})
```

Comment: Don't worry about it. These things aren't always obvious